# Is it possible to have an local instance of Azure Key Vault?

Tags: c#, azure, localhost, local, azure-keyvault

I'm currently working on a solution in C# which will integrate the Azure Key Vault.

If the internet goes down -- I work in Berlin, so not entirely unlikely -- or if I want to rule out network connectivity problems when debugging a solution, is there a way I can set up a local instance?

Comment: What is the key vault is holding, like connection details to a DB, cache?

Comment: @Manti_Core, hypothetically, it could be anything which the Vault may store.  But for my immediate need, I'll be storing text files with RSA private keys as "Secrets" (or possibly "Certificates", but I'm finding it problematic to save them this way).

Comment: you could install certs in your local machine and host an instance give physical path to your project and bind to locally installed certificate or even running kestrel has some cli commands to run with local certs, I don't think doing this for a temporary outage of internet is good.

Comment: @Manti_Core, sometimes I also like to be able to rule out network problems as a reason for things failing.  But wouldn't I need different logic to access certificates from my local machine instead of the Key Vault if I don't have a local instance of the Key Vault?  I'd prefer a solution where I don't need alternative logic.

Comment: No new logic is needed but you need to bind the certificate check this [out](https://dotnetplaybook.com/custom-local-domain-using-https-kestrel-asp-net-core/') , if you cant get the copy of certificate file from azure then use the default dev certificate use the CLIs to enforce secure http

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0) will help you out.

Comment: @Manti_Core, cheers for the information... this looks a lot more involved than simply spinning up a local instance of a vault and changing a Uri to look at localhost instead of azure.  If you have time to give a more detailed overview about what needs to be done and what should be expected, it will be appreciated.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had/have a similar issue, needing a local stub of Azure Key Vault. Just like you, I have found none, so decided to roll my own. It is work in progress, but Key and Secret support is already at MVP state.

As long as spinning up a Docker container is not an issue for you, it might be worth a try.

Please check it out and save it for later if you find it useful: https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault

Answer (score 1):

No, the reason is in the name: **Azure** Key Vault.

But you can setup your code to acquire credentials via a fallback mechanism when running in development mode, e.g. via [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows).

Comment: Is there any way to store files, certificates, or such in "user secrets"?

Comment: UserSecrets is a Json document, so yes if you encode it properly, you can store binary data there. You could also create some local config provider that can load certificates locally if Azure key vault is not available. You can also confiure using environment (Development/Production) to use different configuration sources.

Comment: Would it be possible to configure using different configuration sources with minimal or no branching code, so that the behaviour of a production instance is not substantially different from a developer instance?  What would such a configuration look like?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there's no local standalone software Key Vault, but if you're really interested in making this happen, you have options:

1. [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-key-vault-intro?view=azs-2102) is a part of the on-prem [Azure Stack Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-stack/hub/) which you could host on-prem.
2. Roll your-own encrypted database with a front-end REST web service.

I don't recommend either of these.

Comment: Do we need to host the entire stack hub to host an on-prem azure key vault?  Would we be able to put this on our developer machine (possibly in a VM) without making it grind to a halt?  What might you recommend?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to isolate the Key Vault from the Stack.  There is the ASDK which can be run on a single node (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/asdk/asdk-what-is?view=azs-2102) but it recommends 256Gb RAM. This is not a simple solution.

Comment: 256Gb RAM!?!  Wow!  Ouch!